# C# XNA: getting user input using class function

Tags: c#, xna

I am writing a input method using C# and XNA. In my Game.cs, here is my code:

```
    input = new Input();
    input.Font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Arial");


 protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    string messageString;

    KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
    Keys[] pressedKeys;
    pressedKeys = keyState.GetPressedKeys();
    messageString = " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < pressedKeys.Length; i++)
        messageString = messageString + pressedKeys[i].ToString() + "";
    base.Update(gameTime);
 }



protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    input.Draw(spriteBatch);
     spriteBatch.End();
     base.Draw(gameTime);  
}
```

In my Input.cs, I wrote:

```
public class Input
    {

        public Input()
        {
        }

       public string messageString { get; set; }
       public SpriteFont Font { get; set; }

       public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
            {
            Vector2 messageVector = new Vector2(50, 100);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(Font,messageString,messageVector,Color.White);

            }
    }
```

However, I receive the error like "ArgumentNullException was unhandled: Value can't be null. Parameter name:text" on 
the line

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(Font,messageString,messageVector,Color.White);
```

But I did it in my game.cs. How to fix it please? Here is the screenshot

[image]

Update: problem solved by using the following method. BTW, one should be careful with the class definition(public or private) and its parameter inside.

Comment: What is the full exception message and what line does it occur on?

Comment: Thanks for reply. It occur on the line of "spriteBatch.DrawString(Font,messageString,messageVector,Color.White);
"

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I added more detail.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line, or wait for the program to break when the exception happens. What value is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never assigning your messageString in your Input class to be anything.
Try something like this

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Modified this
    string messageString = String.Empty;
    input.messageString = String.Empty;    


    KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
    Keys[] pressedKeys;
    pressedKeys = keyState.GetPressedKeys();
    for (int i = 0; i < pressedKeys.Length; i++)
        messageString = messageString + pressedKeys[i].ToString() + "";

    // Added this - this should be what resolves the error you were getting
    input.messageString = messageString;

    base.Update(gameTime);
 }
```

We are initialing the messageString to be an empty string, evaluating your pressed keys, and then assigning the message string to be what was evaluated. Note: I am just using your code here, not suggesting that this is the best way to go about what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is perfectly explained. But I have another error saying"'Input.messageString' is inaccessible due to its protection level". What happen please?  I think I use public in my input class already.

Comment: Make sure your Input class is public; from the code you posted it doesn't seem to be (which by default, makes your class private)

'public class Input' instead of 'class Input'

Comment: Yeah, You are right. I fix it now. I should fix both the public class and public string messageString. Thanks again.

Comment: BTW, Bryan, do you have better idea for the input please? This method is modified from microsoft introduction, there are some more long example here but what I need is just a simple input text box to input number from 1-1000

Comment: There are quite a few good questions asked here on SO that directly talk about doing text boxes in XNA, but one of the more popular options is to just download and use an XNA GUI Framework. There are quite a few options out there, so I would just recommend searching here on SO and looking at things like: DigitalRune (paid), Squid (paid?), XNAGUI, XUI, or Nuclex

I've not worked with them myself (rolled my own system - was way more time consuming that I planned), but I hear good things about all of them.

If you can't find what you're looking for, I'd recommend opening up another question on SO